# Can we design a 7 page label using Nicelabel 2019?

Tags: label

I need to design a 7 page label using Nicelabel 2019.Is it possible using some scripts or anything in Nicelabel 2019 tool?

Explored web but not able to get anything relevant.

Anything article or resource which can help me in this way?